# Retrieving characters from a string using google app

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have written a small python program inside my google app. I am using it for extracting out specific characters out of a string like this 
     "+CMGL: 14,"REC READ","+918000459019",,"11/11/04,18:27:53+22"
     C 
     "
I am using split function for it but it's not splitting the string.Any clues why?
it's giving me something this kind of [u'+CMGL: 14,"REC READ","+918000459019",,"11/11/04,18:27:53+22"\n C '] result.

```
def prog (self,strgs):
    self.response.out.write(strgs)
    temp1= strgs
    self.response.out.write(temp1)
    message_split=temp1.split('\n')
    #self.response.out.write(message_split)
    temp=message_split
    self.response.out.write(temp)
    message_split_second=strgs.split(',')
    m_list=message_split[1:]
    self.response.out.write(message_split_second)
    collect_strings=''
    for j in m_list:
        collect_strings=collect_strings+j

    message_txt=collect_strings

    message_date=message_split_second[0]
    message_date=message_date.replace('"',"")
    dates=message_date

    message_time=message_split_second[0]
    message_time=message_time.split('/n')
    message_time=message_time[0]
    message_time=message_time.replace('"',"")
    temp=message_time.split('+')
    message_time=temp[0]
    times=message_time

    cell_number=message_split_second[0]
    cell_number=cell_number.replace('"',"")
    cellnum=cell_number
    return message_txt,dates,times,cellnum
```

Comment: We can't help if you don't post code

Comment: It seems like you're trying to parse a CSV file. Do you know about the [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) module?

Comment: @PetrViktorinIt's a sms message read from a mobile phone.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python split function giving unexpected results in when embedded in google app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187739/python-split-function-giving-unexpected-results-in-when-embedded-in-google-app)

Answer (score 0):

The splits in the first part of your function ought to work. Here's an experiment I just did in Python 2.6:

```
>>> s = '+CMGL: 14,"REC READ","+918000459019",,"11/11/04,18:27:53+22"\n C '
>>> s.split('\n')
['+CMGL: 14,"REC READ","+918000459019",,"11/11/04,18:27:53+22"', ' C ']
>>> s.split(',')
['+CMGL: 14', '"REC READ"', '"+918000459019"', '', '"11/11/04', '18:27:53+22"\n C ']
```

If your `self.response.out.write` calls aren't doing the same thing, try reducing the function to the very shortest thing that displays the odd behaviour. And check that you know exactly what's being passed in as the `strgs` argument.

I can't see much wrong with the rest, except that at one point you try to split on `/n` when you probably meant to use `\n`.

Comment: I have tested this whole code on console and it is working perfectly fine but when I am implementing it inside the app it not showing the appropriate results.